# I've installed xapian via macports, so why does this python app tell me that xapian needs to be installed?

Tags: python, macos, xapian, django-haystack

I'm trying to run a python application on my system. When I try to execute it I get a traceback which ends with something saying I need to install Xapian. So I went ahead an installed xapian-core and xapian-bindings using macports. Then I tried to run the python application again, but got the same traceback. Any ideas about what I should do next? Is there some kind of additional xapian-python thingy I need to install? This kind of thing is all new to me.

I'm using Mac OS 10.6.3, Python 2.6.5 and Django 1.2.1

Here are the last few lines of the traceback I get:

```
File "/Users/nick/dev/ymtest/../ymtest/lib/haystack/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
backend = load_backend(settings.HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE)
File "/Users/nick/dev/ymtest/../ymtest/lib/haystack/__init__.py", line 21, in load_backend
return __import__('haystack.backends.%s_backend' % settings.HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE, {}, {}, [''])
File "/Users/nick/dev/ymtest/../ymtest/lib/haystack/backends/xapian_backend.py", line 18, in <module>
raise MissingDependency("The 'xapian' backend requires the installation of 'xapian'. Please refer to the documentation.")
haystack.exceptions.MissingDependency: The 'xapian' backend requires the installation of 'xapian'. Please refer to the documentation.
```

Comment: first guess with the limited information is the Xapian Python bindings are not installed

Comment: I did install xapian-bindings via macports, but maybe it doesn't include all the necessary bindings.

Comment: I don't know anything about Xapian, but in general, unfortunately, MacPorts packages and non-MacPorts python don't play well together. You should either use MacPorts python or install the package via the normal unix/python channels (e.g., `python setup.py install`)

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me after having the same issue on OS X 10.5:

1. make a macports selfupdate:

   sudo port selfupdate
2. install python 2.6 over macports

   sudo port install python26
3. install python_select

   sudo port install python_select
4. select python 2.6 as system default

   sudo python_select python26
5. install xapian-core

   sudo port install xapian-core
6. install xapian-bindings WITH PYTHON VARIANT

   sudo port install xapian-bindings +python26
7. copy all your python libs from "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages" to
   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages"
   wich is your new default site-packages folder!
8. restart Terminal

Done!